# How to stop Elastic Beanstalk from giving me a new Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Rails app deployed successfully with Elastic Beanstalk, but each time I'm git aws.push, the end result is a new instance with a new Elastic IP, which is not the one I've assigned to my domain name.

So I have to go through this rig-a-ma-roll of allocating the old one to the new instance.  Or alternatively, changing the DNS to point to the new Elastic IP, and then off course, delete the unused Elastic IP so I'm not charged by Amazon.

Can this new Elastic IP creation be prevented in a configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a load balanced environment, your domain should be pointing to the load balancer, so i assume you are on a single instance environment. In this case, you can use .config files and aws cli to automate the DNS record change (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html). Another alternative would be to launch the environment in a VPC and attach an ENI with a fixed IP to the instance, that could avoid DNS caching issues.

But considering the ELB costs, i would not go that far, just launch a load balanced environment with a single instance and register that ELB in DNS (an ALIAS record, if you are using Route53).

Comment: Thanks. I think the first time I switched from an instance to ELB, it switched Elastic IPs, but now that I only use ELB, it uses the Elastic IP of the load balancer, as you stated. Thanks again.